# How to Insert list of data into the Sqlite database

Tags: android

i have created a simple database for inserting the list of data into my sample dB but when i want to send data to database it gives me this error

01-17 15:30:43.015: ERROR/Database(822): Failure 1 (no such column: Sharma) on 0x276e50 when preparing 'INSERT INTO friends Values(Sharma,SaiGeetha,18);""'.

for reference i am pasting the code

```
sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                ArrayList<String>FirstName = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<String>LastName = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<Integer >Age = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                   FirstName.add("SaiGeetha");

                   FirstName.add("Vivek");
                   FirstName.add("Rahul");
                   LastName.add("Sharma");

                   LastName.add("Lilani");
                   LastName.add("Lami");
                    Age.add(18);

                   Age.add(20);
                   Age.add(23);

                sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                        SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                        " (LastName VARCHAR, FirstName VARCHAR," +
                        "  Age INT(3));");

                for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                {
                    sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +


    enter code here

                        SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                            " Values("+LastName.get(i)+","+FirstName.get(i)+","+Age.get(i)+");"+"\"\"");
                }

                /*sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                        SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                        " Values ('Makam','Sai Geetha','India',25);");
                sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                        SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                        " Values ('Chittur','Raman','India',25);");
                sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                        SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                        " Values ('Solutions','Collabera','India',20);");*/

                Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT FirstName, Age FROM " +
                        SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                        " where Age > 10 LIMIT 5", null);

                if (c != null ) {
                    if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FirstName"));
                            int age = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Age"));
                            Log.e("---LIST FROM DATABASE--","---VALUE---"+firstName);
                            Log.e("---LIST FROM DATABASE--","---VALUE---"+age );

                        }while (c.moveToNext());
                    } 
                }
                sampleDB.close();

            } catch (SQLiteException se )
            {
                Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
            } finally {
                if (sampleDB != null) 
                    sampleDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME);
                sampleDB.close();
            }

        }
```

Comment: I am not so sure why you accept the only one of the three answers which is completely wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
" Values('"+LastName.get(i)+"','"+FirstName.get(i)+"',"+Age.get(i)+");");
```

instead of the original. You need to pass String values with quotes in SQL statements. If you do not quote them it is assumed that you reference `columns`.

As noted by njzk2 the usage of other methods is more appropriate. Look at this example: http://learnandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-database.html. Especially the following excerpt:

```
public void createRow(String code, String name) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put("code", code);
    initialValues.put("name", name);
    db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

Comment: also, using contentValues is recommended, more fail-proof, more readable and more maintainable ; and using insert instead of execSQL is clearer too

Comment: @njzk2 i add an reference to that and i totally agree with your point

Comment: Thank you Fyr i have solve by using both of you guys sugesstion

Answer (score 0):

Modifiy your SQL like this:

```
"INSERT INTO " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME + " (LastName, FirstName, Age) Values( "+LastName.get(i)+","+FirstName.get(i)+","+Age.get(i)+")"
```